# Is it possible to register 2 extensions (file types) for a single MIME type?

Tags: registrykey

I have 2 file extensions that need to be associated with the one application. For example I am registering one like:

```
Registry.SetValue(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, ".xyz", "Content Type", "application/x-player", REG_SZ);
Registry.SetValue(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, "MIME\\Database\\Content Type\\application/x-player", "", "", REG_SZ);
Registry.SetValue(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, "MIME\\Database\\Content Type\\application/x-player", "Extension", ".xyz", REG_SZ);
```

Is it possible to register an additional extension to this mime type entry?

Comment: Have you tried it? I'm pretty sure it is since there are other formats such as JPEG-images that have several extensions.

Comment: Actually, I did look through every MIME type in my registry and found no items citing more than one file extension. That's why I asked before committing code for public use.

Comment: Yes but did you try to set it up on your development machine with to see if it actually works?